# CSS3 Transitions

Tags: css, background-color, css-transitions

I want to change the background color of the page when one hovers over a button/div tag using only CSS3 transitions. I want the color to come gradually and hence would like to use a transition effect, but I don't know how to relate the background color of the page to a hover event on a div. Can someone please help me with my code ? Thank You

Comment: I don't think it's possible with CSS only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible in CSS3.

In the future ([CSS4?](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject)), you'll be able to do it as follows:

```css
body {
    background-color: red;
    transition: background-color 1s ease;
}

$body #theButton:hover {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Note the `$` in the second selector; It indicates which element the CSS block applies to. Unfortunately, there's not even a single implementation of this yet, so you'll have to resort to Javascript (which I assume you know how to do. If not, just ask).

---

**Update** (using jQuery)**:**

**CSS:**

```css
​body {
    background: red;
    transition: background-color 1s ease;
}
body.hover {
    background: green;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
​$('#theButton').hover(function(){
    $('body').addClass('hover');
}, function(){
    $('body').removeClass('hover');
});​​​​​​​​
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mWY88/1/

---

For maximum efficiency, you should cache your selectors.

Comment: Ohh thats pretty cool, haven't seen that before. Yes then please help me out with the javascript for this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Ash1995 - are you using jQuery? That would make things a lot easier.

Comment: I am learning jQuery so as long as it is simple I will be able to understand it.

Comment: @Ash1995 - I provided you with a very simple example - shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you can change the body background-color very easily with CSS3 transition animation like [I'm doing it here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ae4wv/). I got the logic from [here](http://desandro.github.com/motion-emotion/).